# Set xxxx = ActiveWorkbook error on some PCs, not others

Tags: vba, object, excel-2007

I have a user getting an error message when trying to utilize a macro.

1. The macro functions for myself and 8 people who have tested it.
2. We are all on Win7, including the person getting the error. We are all using Office 2007, including the person getting the error.
3. There are two places in the code where this command is used:

   ```
   Public Function GenerateList(ByVal TargetRow, ByVal TargetColumn)
   Dim DateRange As String, LocationLost As Integer, LocationName As String, SearchRow         As Integer, PasteRow As Integer, MainWkbk As Workbook, NextWkbk As Workbook
   Set MainWkbk = ActiveWorkbook
   SearchRow = 2
   PasteRow = 2
   ```

and, later in the code when I am creating a new workbook:

```
    Dim Aname As String
    Const csPath As String = "location path redacted"
    Aname = "Gaps" & LocationName & DateRange
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=csPath & Aname & ".xls"
    Set NextWkbk = ActiveWorkbook
```

The user who is experiencing the error is not at my location, so I had them share their desktop and watched them step through the code. The macro made it all the way to the second workbook Set command without an error. So, the first Set command works for them but the second does not.

Their software did not have a developer tab but the editor came up with a keyboard command.

Any ideas around why the second Set command would be generating an error when the same (essentially) Set command works earlier in the code?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, is the drive letter the same at both locations? I encountered a similar mysterious problem and it turned out that my office used "J:\" for a shared drive where another location used "T:\" for the same drive.

Comment: First thing to do when troubleshooting office is start it as a com server. This means stock standard settings are used. No customisation. `excel/a` in Start - Run. Is their Excel still different to yours? Your macro won't be available, get them to paste it in and rerun it.

Comment: In the line before the error do `msgbox activeworkbook`. Note error details.

Comment: Did the file `csPath & Aname & ".xls"` actually get saved? What if you `Set NextWkbk = Workbooks(Aname & ".xls")` instead of ActiveWorkbook?

Comment: stobin - thanks for the idea. we're saving to a network drive that we all have the appropriate permissions for, so to avoid the very issue you mentioned i used the full path name rather than a drive abbreviation.

Comment: PatricK - no, the file did not get saved though the new workbook did appear on their screen. Thanks for the idea; I'm trying the anti-ActiveWorkbook approach now.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the new Workbook to the object variable as soon as it's created then you don't need to rely on ActiveWorkBook at all

```
   Set NextWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
   NextWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=csPath & Aname & ".xls"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221273(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but unfortunately it did not work. It appears to be working for everyone physically at my location in MN, but after recruiting a few more testers in NY to try it will not work for any of them. They all have full permissions for the network drive in question so it must be some kind of authentication issue I guess...